# how to convert these string columns so that i can put the data to the regressor

Tags: python, dataset, pandas, data-cleaning, data-science-model

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yQR1xJvzWd2UGgGQS2bHhdywZEE_Nu0J/view?usp=sharing

I have to change the name of the columns: city, batting_team, bowling_team, batsman, non_striker,   bowler. These column have string value and I have to change it to int/float to put it through the regressor. I know we can use one hot encoder but I don't know how to code it.